# What is this piece of code regarding scanf?

Tags: c++

I was looking through my friend's obj loading code. He has done it in C++; the code is:

```
bool LoadObj(char* given){
    char tempText[60];
    std::ifstream OB(given);
    OB.seekg(0,OB.end);  int length = OB.tellg() ; OB.seekg(0,OB.beg);

    char* STREAM = new char[length];
    OB.read(STREAM,length);
    OB.close();

    char *t,dump[20];
    int Number_Of_Vertices,Number_Of_faces;



    t = strstr(STREAM,"vertices");
    sscanf(&STREAM[&t[0]-&STREAM[0]-10],"%s # %i vertices",&dump,&Number_Of_Vertices);
    printf("\nthere are %i vertices",Number_Of_Vertices);

    t = strstr(STREAM,"faces");
    sscanf(&STREAM[&t[0]-&STREAM[0]-10],"%s # %i faces",&dump,&Number_Of_faces);
    printf("\nthere are %i faces",Number_Of_faces); 

 ......
```

When I tested this by loading an obj file, it opened correctly. However I do not understand the first argument to `sscanf()`, namely: `&STREAM[&t[0]-&STREAM[0]-10]`. Please explain how does it work?

Comment: Can't you ask your friend? It's their code, they should own up to it.

Comment: I can ask him but he is busy till friday.

Comment: this is the obj file http://pastebin.com/pvi7bU6y

Comment: To tell you the truth, this is horribly written. I'm sure it's correct, but it is what one may call a future maintenance nightmare.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
t = strstr(STREAM,"vertices");
```

`t` will point to the position of the substring `"vertices"`, inside `STREAM`.

`&t[0]` is the address of the first character in `"vertices"`. Equivalent to `t` itself.
The same applies for `&STREAM[0]`, it is the address of the first character of `STREAM`. Subtracting them gives you the starting index of `t`.

So your friend wants to read from `STREAM`, starting ten characters *before* `t`.

All of this is far more clearly expressed by a simple `t - 10`.

Comment: No, he wants to *read* from `STREAM`, starting ten characters before `t`. More specifically read using the format string `%s # %i vertices`. Also: since it reads only ten characters before `t`, the string and the integer can't be too large.

Comment: @gurka - You are indeed correct. I had it mistakenly branded into my mind the OP had `sprintf` there, and not `sscnaf`.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know why it's done that way but

`&STREAM[&t[0]-&STREAM[0]-10]`

is the same as

`t-10`

It's 10 characters before the start of "vertices" (and "faces")

Answer (score 3):

Does your friend frequent some Obfuscated C contests?

`&t[0]` takes the address of the first byte in `*t`. That address is of course what `t` already contains.

Similar for `&STREAM[0]`, which is the same address as `STREAM`.

So, `&t[0]-&STREAM[0]` computes the number of bytes (chars) between `t` and the start of `STREAM`. If you use that as an index into `STREAM` and take the address of *that* byte `&STREAM[&t[0]-&STREAM[0]]` - again you get the address that was already in `t`.

And if you subtract 10 bytes from that, `&STREAM[&t[0]-&STREAM[0]-10]`, you end up with `t - 10`...

Answer (score 1):

&STREAM[&t[0]-&STREAM[0]-10]  =  &STREAM[ addressof(t[0]) - addressof(STREAM[0]) - 10]. It gives the offset of `t` in `STREAM` minus 10. Writing `t - 10` would have been the same knowing that `t` and `STREAM` are pointers on the same buffer.